# How can I add NavMesh path to pass through the door in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I am trying to use NavMeshAgent to move the player around in Unity.

But the doorway is not connected in NavMesh so the player can't pass through.

is there any way to add navmesh path at the doorway so that the player can go through?

I tried to change step height and max slop but does not work...

[image]

Comment: Is the door too thin?

Comment: @BugFinder I dont think so... I can go through the door if I move the player with `Input.GetAxis`. And setting agent radius to small value also doesn't fix the issue...

Comment: Depends how you move it. But it could be you defined the agent as wider than the door note you need to have the margin shown x2 plus size of agent to fit

Comment: Is the door static? If push comes to shove you can always use an off-mesh link for this stuff.

Comment: @BugFinder Even if I put the agent thinner it doesn't work.

Comment: @Voidsay Thank you! Adding the off-mesh link to the door component solved the issue!

Comment: Odd I’ve never had issues as long as the margin on the door etx was sufficient for the agent to pass.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Nav Mesh dynamic
for this, you need to add Nav Mesh obstacle to your door
and make it non-static.
also make sure that you have checked the "carve" .

[image: Nav Mesh obstacle component]

The agent can pass through the doorway if you open the door or move it up at run time.
Make sure your character radious is thin enough as well and also adjust height of the agent if you want to move the door up.

[image: Before opening the door]

[image: After Opening the Door]

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. I tried to attach the Navmesh obstacle but it didn't work. The door has the frame so even the door opens, there is the level difference at the bottom due to the door frame, which prevents create nav mesh path....

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding `Off Mesh Link` to the door object like @Voidsay suggested.

After adding the `Off Mesh Link`, it correctly shows the path and I can pass through the door.

[image]

Just selecting the floor objects both outside and inside the door to `Start` and `End` in `Off Mesh Link` did the trick.
[image]